# (405) Method Not Allowed with Visual Studio 2017 (NuGet) Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, nuget, nuget-package, http-proxy

The Error that I get in the Visual Studio Package Manager Output is:

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

Configuring a proxy in `NuGet.config` or not configuring a proxy had no effect on the result.

nuget.org in my config is:

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" />
```

If I set the environments http_proxy to my companies proxy I can reproduce this using nuget.exe (`NuGet Version: 4.7.0.5148`)

```
nuget list -source nuget.org -ForceEnglishOutput

Unable to load the service index for source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

If I clear the environment http_proxy the same command starts listing packages. (which I abort using `crtl+c`).

I know that there is a difference between the package manager in visual studio and nuget.exe.

As I understand both use the same nuget.config file.
As I see it somehow the package manager uses a proxy setting that I did not check. I can not find where that would be.

Is there a proxy setting that I did not check?
Am I missing something else?

EDIT:
When I remove the proxy Settings from Nuget.Config and then update a package source in visual studio my Nuget.Config Settings are rewritten which restores my proxy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio kept a copy of the config in memory. Every time the package manager connects it rewrites `nuget.config`.

So my issue was solved by closing vs2017, editing the `nuget.config` by hand and restarting visual studio.